# javascript remove using reduce

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to just get particular values in an obj with the status of 'xyz'

```
user.friends =
CoreMongooseArray [
{ _id: 5b11824350c0011afe9ca310,
user:
 { profile: [Object],
   _id: 5b11805a50c0011afe9ca2fe,
   username: 'user1' },
status: 'abc' },
{ _id: 5b191033d240ab4a10ffb54f,
user:
 { profile: [Object],
   _id: 5b0ec81f958f5b4919b83c40,
   username: 'user2' },
status: 'xyz' } ]
```

I'm using

```
user.friends.reduce((a, t) => a + (t.type === 'xyz' ? 0 : 1), 0);
```

but it only returns 1, rather than just the object with the username user2, why?

Comment: I don't see any `type` property...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> but it only returns 1, rather than just the object with the username user2, why?

Because that's the last return value of your callback. This is how [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) works.

If you want to find one particular object in an array matching a criterion, `reduce` isn't the tool to use (though you could force it to work, just as you can use a screwdriver as a hammer if you try hard enough). The tool to use is [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```
const oneXYZFriend = user.friends.find(e => e.status === 'xyz');
```

(Notice I changed the test from `e.type === 'xyz'` to `e.status === 'xyz'`, since your objects have a `status` property, not a `type` property.)

If you want to find several objects in an array matching a criterion, you'd use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
const xyzFriends = user.friends.filter(e => e.status === 'xyz');
```